# Office 365 Management API activity/feed/subscriptions APIs returning InternalServerError

Tags: azure-active-directory

Am researching activity audits for the last couple days using an asp.net MVC project. I was using contentType=Audit.Exchange and contentType=Azure.ActiveDirectory successfully since the last half of yesterday and this morning up until about two hours ago.

I made no changes to my authorization/authentication code and the tokens look good. Also no changes to the calls themselves. I added some json handling for the response to list subscriptions and when I ran the app to test that code, suddenly I am getting an InternalServerError response to start subscription, list subscriptions and stop subscription. The error is returned after a long timeout (in fact I had to increase the default timeout value).

So as of about two hours ago all the APIs are returning InternalServerError after a long timeout. This is happening on the following APIs:
   /activity/feed/subscriptions/start
   /activity/feed/subscriptions/list
   /activity/feed/subscriptions/stop

The body of the response message is empty. So does not include any error info as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/office-365/office-365-management-activity-api-reference.

Seems crazy this could be a service outage, so I must be missing something really elemental?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm. With no further changes to the code, now am getting HTTP 200 responses. If that was a service outage, that was a heck of a long outage for 99.9% uptime.